# Maven not including dependencies in Jar file

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, neo4j

I'm trying to connect to a Neo4j 2.2.10 server using the neo4j-jdbc-driver v3.0. I am able to connect without any problems within the IDE but when I try to do the same from a Jar file I get a no suitable driver found exception as if the dependency isn't available.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:neo4j:http://localhost
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    ....
```

Here is the relevant part of my my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>    
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>    
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I looked into including dependencies with Maven elsewhere on the forum and so that is where the plugin is taken from. However, I don't think it is including the dependency based on the error.

Previously, I was using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I was able to interact with a v3.0.3 Neo4j server via bolt from a Jar with no issues.

What am I doing wrong?

**Thanks for any advice!**

Comment: Are you pakaging the jar from the IDE itself using maven(mave install) ??

Comment: From the IDE via the maven plugin using maven install.

Comment: Yes,are you doing that??

Comment: Yes, I'm doing maven clean, maven install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify yourself if the driver is included in the resulting artifact (supposing its name is assembly.jar):

```
jar tf target/assembly.jar | fgrep jdbc
```

It probably is, though.

I think the problem comes from the fact that the driver is automatically registered using the Service Provider Interface (SPI), by listing the classes in `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. However, because the assembly plugin packages the dependency jars inside the assembly jar instead of exploding them and creating an uber-jar (like the shade plugin can), the SPI files are not scanned. See [this blog post](http://blog.xebia.com/jar-with-deps-dont-like-meta-infservices/) for example.

I suggest you try the shade plugin instead, configured with a `ServicesResourceTransformer`.

---

**Update**

If the SPI mechanism doesn't work in your context (jar loaded as a plugin by a container application), you can register the driver yourself if there's a place in the code you know will be called before the driver is used (some initialization service for the plugin, for example, maybe by implementing [`Plugin.onLoad()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/plugin/Plugin.html#onLoad())?): just create a instance of the driver, it will register itself.

```
try {
    new org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpDriver();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.error("Could not load HttpDriver for Neo4j", e);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I followed your suggestion with some success. When using the `ManifestResourceTransformer` in a basic test Jar it works, however I am not trying to create a standalone executable Jar. When I extend the class in the same way I need to for my project and try to run the jar as an executable I get the error `Could not load or find main class...`. I tried the `ServicesResourceTransformer` instead of and in tandem with the `ManifestResourceTransformer` but it no longer runs once extended. I also tried it as a plugin (what I'm trying to achieve) and it can't find the jdbc still.

Comment: If it's not for a standalone jar, do you actually need to produce a single artifact using the assembly or shade plugin? Can't you just use the dependencies in a regular way (classpath argument on the command line, `WEB-INF/lib`, whatever), which would avoid all this mess? Anyway, for the driver to work, you need to have a `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file in your resulting jar: `jar tf target/assembly.jar | fgrep META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`.

Comment: I'm trying to create a plugin to run on a server (Spigot if you're familiar), so I just put the jar in a plugins folder and boot the server.`jar tf target/assembly.jar | fgrep META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` returns `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`.

Comment: OK, I was thinking about a plugin indeed. The way the jar is loaded might prevent the SPI mechanism from working. See my updated answer for a possible manual solution.

Comment: There is indeed an onEnable method which your suggestion has worked with. Thank you for the help!